# JTable DefaultTableModel удаление столбца

Tags: jtable, java, swing

Есть необходимость реализовать таблицу с динамически удаляемыми и добавляемыми столбцами.
Насколько я понимаю, DefaultTableModel не поддерживает удаления столбцов. Посоветуйте, как в таком случае поступить. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в общем, то нужно удалить столбец из массива данных, удалить строку с названием удаляемого столбца из массива с именами, а потом вызвать fireDataChanged(). Массивы придётся использовать из серии ArrayList или чего-нибудь подобного, с возможностью добавления-удаления. С AbstractTableModel у меня прокатывало. Возможно, есть и другие варианты